# The browser opens the image when its path is typed in address-bar, but does Not display it as background-image. Why?

Tags: php, html, css, url, path

In this SSCCE, I have used two `div`s with `background-image` having a value pointing to the same image, but using different paths. The image is not displayed in the second `div`.

The second div demonstrates the problem in my real code. The `C:/xampp/htdocs` part of the URL comes dynamically, and I append it to the rest of the path using PHP with the rest of the URL which always remains the same.

As you can see, I am using local XAMPP server during development, but this image is not getting displayed.

**When I copy-paste this path, i.e. `C:/xampp/htdocs/Tests/Test44/index.png`, in Chrome's addess bar, it changes it to `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Tests/Test44/index.png`, and displays the image.**

What can I do to fix this?

**Markup:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="the-div" style="background-image:url(index.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">Instagram</div>

    <div class="another" style="background-image:url(C:/xampp/htdocs/Tests/Test44/index.png); background-position:center center; background-repeat:no-repeat;">Twitter</div>

</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color:black;
}

div {
    font: 0px/0 a;
    border: coral 5px solid;
    margin:5px;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: A filepath is not the same thing as an URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said a filepath is not the same as an URL.

Just remove the "C:/xampp/htdocs" part and the background-image will be shown.

[Difference between absolute and relative URL](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abwp)